# Find the out degree of directed graph using networkx 2.2

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to find the out degree of graph

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph() 

for n in G.nodes():
     v.append(1/ G.out_degree(n))
```

however it shows 'Graph' object has no attribute 'out_degree'

Answer (score 2):

`out_degree()` is not implemented for the Graph class, in such a case you should use the `degree()` method.
My guess is that there is some statement missing in your code between the creation of G and the call of the `out_degree()` method that changes `G` from Digraph to Graph since the exception raised is

> 'Graph' object has no attribute 'out_degree'

and not

> 'DiGraph' object has no attribute 'out_degree'